# Combining / Structuring multiple knockout observable arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

I have 2 observable arrays in my view model:

```
self.main = ko.observablearray();
self.sub = ko.observablearry();
```

Main is loaded with a getjson call and returns 12 items with a description / sort order (i.e. 1-12) into the self.main array and the sub returns child descriptions to the main.

The json for main return:

```
<storedProc_Result>
<ID>4</ID>
<mainDescription>
      foo foo foo
</mainDescription>
<SortOrder>1</SortOrder>
</storedProc_Result>
```

The json for sub return:

```
<storedProc2_Result>
<SortOrder>1.1</SortOrder>
<ID>21</ID>
<SubDescription>bar bar bar</SubDescription>
</storedProc2_Result>
<storedProc2_Result>
<SortOrder>1.2</SortOrder>
<ID>23</ID>
<SubDescription>bar bar bar</SubDescription>
</storedProc2_Result>
```

How will I loop through and combine these 2 arrays based off of the SortOrder value so I can do a foreach loop on my View page?  I.E.

- Main Description 1

  - Sub Description 1.1
  - Sub Description 1.2
- Main Description 2

  - Sub Description 2.1
- ...

Answer (score 1):

### 1. The Data

Let's first explore the data you've provided in a more readable format:

#### Main

```
{
  ID: 4,
  mainDescription: "foo foo foo",
  SortOrder: "1"
}
```

#### Sub

```
{
  ID: 21,
  SubDescription: "bar bar bar",
  SortOrder: "1.1"
}
```

---

### 2. The viewmodels

From your desired output, we learn that we need:

#### An `AppViewModel`

```
{
  mains: [ /* MainViewModel */ ]
}
```

#### A `MainViewModel`

```
{ 
  title: "foo foo foo",
  numberLabel: "1",
  subs: [ /* SubViewModel */ ],

  // The label as a number
  sortOrder: parseInt("1", 10)
}
```

#### A `SubViewModel`

```
{
  title: "bar bar bar",
  numberLabel: "1.1",

  // We sort by the second number in the label
  sortOrder: parseInt("1.1".split(".")[1], 10),

  // We group by the first part of the label
  groupKey: "1.1".split(".")[0]
}
```

---

### 3. The views

With the structure of viewmodels as proposed, we can create the view:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: mains">
  <li>
    <p data-bind="text: title + ' ' + numberLabel">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: subs">
      <li data-bind="text: title + ' ' + numberLabel"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

### 4. Sorting viewmodel instances

Because we have numeric `sortKey` props, we can do a numeric compare to sort:

```
// Sort utils
const numericSort = (x, y) => x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0;
const vmSort = (vm1, vm2) => numericSort(vm1.sortKey, vm2.sortKey);
```

---

### 5. Grouping viewmodels

We can group a list of SubViewModel instances by their `groupKey`:

```
const groupSubs = subs => subs.reduce(
  (gs, s) => Object.assign(
    gs,
    { [s.groupKey]: (gs[s.groupkey] || []).concat(s) }
  ), { }
)
```

Now, we can create a nice chain from data to app using `ko.pureComputed` instances.

```
const subData = ko.observableArray([]);
const subVMs = ko.pureComputed(
  () => subData().map(SubViewModel)
);
const subGroups = ko.pureComputed(
  () => groupSubs(subVMs())
);

const mainData = ko.observableArray([]);
const mainVMs = ko.pureComputed(
  () => mainData().map(m => MainViewModel(m, subGroups))
);

ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel(mainVMs));
```

### Working example

This flow illustrated in a working example:

```js
const mains = ko.observableArray([]);
const subs = ko.observableArray([]);

const subGroup = sub => sub.sortOrder.split(".")[0]

const subsByMain = ko.pureComputed(() =>
  subs()
    .map(sub => [subGroup(sub), sub])
    .reduce(
      (groups, [id, sub]) => Object.assign(
        groups, { [id]: (groups[id] || []).concat(sub) }  
      ), {}
    )
);

const Main = function(config, groups) {
  this.title = config.description;
  this.sortOrder = config.sortOrder;
  
  this.subs = ko.pureComputed(() => 
    groups()[config.sortOrder] || []
  );
};

ko.applyBindings({ 
  mains: ko.pureComputed(() => 
    mains().map(cfg => new Main(cfg, subsByMain))
  )
});


const getMainData = cb => setTimeout(() => cb([
  { id: 1, description: "foo foo foo", sortOrder: "1" },
  { id: 2, description: "bar bar bar", sortOrder: "2" }
]), 500);

const getSubData = cb => setTimeout(() => cb([
  { id: 3, description: "foo 1", sortOrder: "1.1" },
  { id: 4, description: "foo 2", sortOrder: "1.2" },
  { id: 5, description: "bar 1", sortOrder: "2.1" },
  { id: 6, description: "bar 2", sortOrder: "2.3" }
]), 300);

getMainData(mains);
getSubData(subs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: mains">
  <li>
    <p data-bind="text: title + ' ' + sortOrder">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: subs">
      <li data-bind="text: description + ' ' + sortOrder"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you for the great answer.  It was very instructional.